# How to remove Sign in with Apple ID overlay in swift ios app?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, apple-sign-in

When I open my app "Sign in with Apple ID" overlay is shown. I don't support Apple Sign in. There is in app purchase in the app and when the user wants to purchase, the same login overlay is shown, instead of the normal purchase overlay.

On Simulator the overlay is always shown and I am not able login using any account (real or sandbox) though I am not able to test in app purchase with the simulator either (I tried with iOS 14 and iOS 15 simulators.)
On device it is better after entering credentials, I can test in app purchase but it is still annoying that I need to enter my password because I don't need to enter when I use other apps.

What could be the reason? How can I remove it?

I have subscription based in app purcahse in my app.

[image]

Comment: Login in your simulator from the setting option and try. It should work. If still face issue reset simulator and login in setting and then try.

Answer (score 0):

I think you signed out from iPhone simulator/device (you can check in Phone settings). So you need to login & setup with appleID in device/simulator. then alert will not appear every time. You can try apple login in simulator but still you need to check in real device for IAP.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUZK0.jpg